# Metasploit - Does the multi handler sends the payload, or just listens for connection

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter, reverse-shell

Does the metasploit module: exploit/multi/handler

- sends payloads to stagers?
- Or does it just listens for an incoming connection like a netcat
  listener?
- Or does it do both, as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. The `exploit/multi/handler` is more of a stub for whatever payload handler you need to run. So whichever payload you select (with `set payload ...`) is responsible for doing whatever it needs, just like if you were running it from a regular exploit module.

So yes, from a multi-handler, any of the following could happen:

- A simple socket listener/connection, like netcat (for plain shell payloads)
- A handler for stager payloads that uploads Meterpreter (for `meterpreter/*` payloads)
- A handler for single-stage (stageless?) Meterpreter (for `meterpreter_*` payloads)